# datalist inside a datalist

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a question about datalist and selected item template

Here is how it works:

On a webpage I have a 2 datalists which are getting data from their respective tables:
DepartmentList calling DepartmentTable
CategoryList calling CategoryTable

Each Department has one or more Category.

What I want is:

My Department are coming on the screen (the category doesn't appear until a deparment is selected)

```
Dept1
Dept2
Dept3
```

The user click Dept 2 (for ex) and then will have the category appearing inside the Departement (something like this)

```
Dept1
Dept2
    Cat1
    Cat2
    Cat3
Dept3
```

So at the end I have a menu made of 2 datalists

I tried the put CategoryList in the selected Item Template of the DepartmentList but nothing happens.

If you have suggestions thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing a square treeview to me.

Comment: How are you binding the CategoryList?